# In Visual Studio, programming .NET, how can I tell a file reference from a project reference?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, reference, projects-and-solutions

I intend to combine a bunch of .NET projects, in separate solutions, into one solution.  Some of the projects appear in more than one solution.  It all happens to be C#, but I don't think that's relevant.  We have a full range of projects, class project, windows forms, web site, web services.

The links between the projects are a mix of file references (Add Reference -> Browse Tab) and project references (Add Reference -> Projects Tab).  I will want to change the file references to project references when all the projects are in the same solution.

Is there anywhere that the Visual Studio UI (I am using Visual Studio 2008) allows me to distinguish a project reference from a file reference?  Failing that, is there an easy way to tell by looking at the project file with another tool, or even a text editor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Specific Version` property will not appear in project references.

Comment: Fantastic tip!  Very keyboard friendly.  I undocked the properties window.  Then I bounced down the list of references with the arrow key, just looking for the Specific Version property to show up.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Project -> Project Dependencies. It will only show project references. The other references would be assembly references.

Comment: This tip works in VS2005 as well. "Specific Version" is cool, but doesn't exist apparently until VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

VS shows properties for all files in a solution/project and if you look at the properties in the properties window you can see the path, thats how i do it.